# Write jest unit testcases for exception handling getting issue on while run

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, nestjs

This is my controller class:

```
        @Put()
            async updateUser(@BodyToClass() user: UpsertUserDto): Promise<UpsertUserDto> {
                try {
                    return await this.userService.updateUser(user);
                } catch (e) {
                    throw new HttpException(e.message, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                }
            }
```

This is my Usercontroller.spec test class, I am writing the testcases for exception handling for negative cases.

While running getting error on this line:

```
        ".then(() => done.fail('Client controller should return INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR 500 '))
```

Here is my failure message from Jest:

> at Env.fail (../node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:722:61) at user/user.controller.spec.ts:51:33 at Object. (user/user.controller.spec.ts:50:15)

I am not sure where I am doing mistake or whether there is other way to handle the exception in nestjs.

```
       it('should throw INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR if user not update', async (done) => {
          const expectedResult = undefined;
          const testuser =  new  UpsertUserDto();
          testuser.id = '123';
          jest.spyOn(userservice, 'updateUser').mockResolvedValue(expectedResult);
          await usercontroller.updateUser(testuser)
           .then(() => done.fail('Client controller should return INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR 500 '))
           .catch((error) => {
             expect(error.status).toBe(500);
             expect(error.message).toMatchObject({error: ' INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR', statusCode: 500});
             done();
            });

    });
```

Comment: cursor is pointing on this line(above ) which i added.

Comment: at Env.fail (../node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:722:61)
      at user/user.controller.spec.ts:51:33
      at Object.<anonymous> (user/user.controller.spec.ts:50:15)

Comment: : Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: getting this error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `mockResolvedValue` in your `jest.spyOn` which means that in a `.then` chain, the `.catch` will **never** be executed. Looking at your code, all that's happening it your `UserService` method returns `undefined` and as there is no logic around it, the controller then returns that `undefined` meaning there's no error to be caught. If you are trying to test an error, you should be using `mockRejectedValue` instead. Also, it's usually not the best practice to mix using `async/await` with using a `done` callback, as it can lead to some weird situations.

And lastly, Jest has a built in way to check for errors from a function. Your test *could* look something like this instead:

```js
it('should throw INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR if user not update', async () => {
  const testuser =  new  UpsertUserDto();
  testuser.id = '123';
  jest.spyOn(userservice, 'updateUser').mockRejectedValue(new Error('There was an error'));
  await expect(usercontroller.updateUser(testuser)).rejects.toThrow(HttpException);
  await expect(usercontroller.updateUser(testuser)).rejects.toThrow('There was an error');
});
```

I suggest you spend some time [reading Jest's documentation](https://jestjs.io) and possibly [looking at some examples](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs) to get your feet on the ground with testing.

Comment: Thank you so much Jay..sure I will read jest's documentation.

Comment: clicking this link 'looking at some examples'....seems site is not reachable

Comment: Typo in the link. Fixed now